# Why does PureScript traceM print strings from previous values?

Tags: purescript

In `ghci` with the same steps I get:

```
λ> bar
hello
Just 500
```

but with `pulp repl` I get this instead:

```
> bar
'hi'
'hello'
(Just 500)
```

Full session:

```
> import Debug.Trace (traceM)
> import Data.Maybe
> :paste
… foo :: Maybe Int
… foo = do
…     traceM "hi"
…     Just 5
… 
> foo
'hi'
(Just 5)

> :paste
… bar :: Maybe Int
… bar =  do
…     traceM "hello"
…     Just 500
… 
> bar
'hi'
'hello'
(Just 500)
```

Comment: This is not a problem with `traceM`, but a problem with PureScript REPL, which has problems with console output. If you put the same code in the `main` function and run it, it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if there's an open issue I can follow?

Comment: No, I do not...